# Can't get Discriminator value mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

in my situation I can't get the value I need :

My objects is like this :

```
const ReportSchema = new Schema({
  number: { type: Number, default: 1 },
})

const ReportProfile = Report.discriminator('ReportProfile', new Schema({
  profile: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Profile' }
}))
```

And I call my object with this method :

```
return this.reportStore.findProfileReport({profile: contentId})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed something

```
const options = {
  discriminatorKey: 'type',
  timestamps: true
}
```

After that, add this in your model like that :

```
const ReportSchema = new Schema({
  number: { type: Number, default: 1 },
}, options) // don't forget the option
```